# Prevent sed from adding newlines at the end of files

Tags: git, bash, sed

I have a large project where I want to replace module names using the following command:

`find app/ -type f -exec sed -i '' 's/Foo/Bar/g' {} +`

This works great, but sed also adds newlines to the end of all the files (even if it can't find any Foo's to replace).

How can I prevent sed from adding these newlines?

I'm on OSX, using the BSD version of sed.

(For the record, I very much agree with sed here, but I dont want to pollute the git history of the project.)

Comment: This behavior (adding a missing newline at EOF) is not found in GNU sed

Comment: I'm on OSX, using the BSD version: https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/sed.1.html

Comment: Are you saying sed is adding a blank line at the end of the file or that the original file does not have a terminating newline and sed is adding it? If the former your sed is broken, if the latter then your input files are not text files per the POSIX standard so whatever sed or any other UNIX tool does with them is undefined behavior in POSIX.

Comment: The latter. As I said, I agree with sed, but don't want to pollute the git history .

Answer (score 8):

Perl to the rescue:

```
perl -i -pe 's/Foo/Bar/g'
```

Perl doesn't add newlines.