# How to prevent sed from inserting empty line at end of file?

Tags: sed, newline

I have a file.

`file.txt`:

```
aa  
bb
## No empty Line at end of file.
```

I use sed to modify `file.txt` directly.

```
sed -i "" 's/aa/mm/g' file.txt
```

Result:

```
mm   
bb    
## a empty Line at end of file.
```

Sed inserts an empty line at the end of the file. How to stop this?

Comment: `sed` does not insert an empty line at the end of file. It ensures that each line (including the last one) ends with a newline character (and this is a good thing, in general).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prevent sed from adding newlines at the end of files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38354725/prevent-sed-from-adding-newlines-at-the-end-of-files)

Comment: Settings/version/implementation? `hexdump -c xxx` -> `0000000   a   b   c  \n   d   e   f`; `hexdump -c xxx`; `hexdump -c xxx` -> `0000000   x   y   c  \n   d   e   f`. New lines intact, even the trailing one is still missing.